# The Line Between "Legitimate SO Question" and "Opinion-Based"

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons, opinion-based

I've been here a long time (since Beta, though I wasn't active and lost the badge). In the entire time I've participated in this community, I've always understood "opinion-based" not to mean "there's an opinion-component to the question" ... because easily 75+% of all answers have some degree of opinion to them.

Instead, I've always understood it to mean "there is no one correct answer to this question, you're only (or at least mostly) asking for opinions".

But today I saw a question (not mine) closed, despite asking for a primarily technical answer. Without focusing on the specifics, it was generally asking "my language has a standard library with multiple methods for doing the same thing: is one of those methods better than the other, for instance more reliable?"

Not only did this question get 4 close votes for being opinion-based, but a moderator removed my comment arguing that it was a legitimate question. So it seems clear I've lost my understanding of where the line is, and I guess what I'm asking is ... where's the line now?

Can anyone point me to a way of clarifying when we're allowed to ask: "there's two ways to skin a cat, should I pick one?"

Comment: I see a problem in the question asking for which method is “better”—the OP needs to define “better”. Better how? Faster? More efficient? More appropriate to a specific situation? Are they _actually_ asking for the differences between the methods? What did the spec or docs reveal when they researched the methods? Etc.

Comment: Ok, for the sake of argument let's say it asks for "are there technical downsides to one approach or the other": is that enough?  Keep in mind new learners often don't know enough to ask more than that, so while of course we don't want bad questions, if we set the bar higher than that we're basically guaranteeing lots of new people asking for technical best practices will be closed.

Comment: *"are there technical downsides to one approach or the other"* isn't opinion based, because the question is clear and be argued with evidence, but it could be too broad, depending on the actual question.

Comment: Thanks.  I strongly agree, but are there any further "rules" or "definition"?  If I feel the closers and/or mods get it wrong, can I point to anything except the close text itself ("Many good questions generate some degree of opinion ...") to either show them as much, or teach myself why I'm actually the one in the wrong?

Comment: It could simply be a mis-closing and may not mean that the line has changed. That happens every day.  There is still the reopen system. Leaving a comment discussing the ontopicness is usually a useful thing to do. The moderator may have removed it in error or for other reasons. Without more details it's really hard to say.

Comment: As for opinion based: the system wants to avoid popularity polls. Whenever it comes down primarily to personal preference you don't learn very much. With the low number of votes typically given you may not learn anything useful at all.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for black and white rules.  There aren't any.  The close reasons themselves are opinion-based; were this not the case, we could dispense with the voting system, because all close votes would be unambiguous.

Comment: I'm not so much asking for black and white rules as saying "there's a wide spectrum of further definition possible, beyond just two sentences of close text; *besides* black and white  rules that can't exist, is there anything else that *does* exist on that spectrum?"  To me it's a "if no one knows the rules how can we follow them?" issue.  If closing legitimate new people questions is a problem, I don't see how to solve that problem if we can't clarify that they are legit in the first place.

Comment: "*"are there technical downsides to one approach or the other": is that enough?*" not really. It's very likely that both approaches have upsides and downsides. Otherwise there wouldn't be two approaches, there would only be one.

Comment: The close reason used to say "*primarily* opinion-based". Losing that in the interest of "simplicity" was a major regression, in my opinion. I continue to interpret the close reason as if this adverb is still attached to it, and I encourage others to do the same.

Comment: 4 close votes? How old is it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way you solve this problem is simple: **state some criteria for the decision making process in your question.**

Questions that contain words like "which is better" are inherently unanswerable without including some means for judging "better."  Instead of asking "which is better," ask "which of these options most effectively meets [my specific requirements]?"

This is why Software Recommendations [requires](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story; and
- Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Comment: While all this is true in a perfect world, we live in an imperfect one. When a novice *doesn't* do this, but just asks "should I do A or B", is that right for SO?

Comment: @machineghost no, it is not.

Comment: Poorly written newbie questions like that can often be salvaged with an edit by an experienced user, @machineghost. That's what I'd recommend you do whenever possible. If it's just irredeemably opinion-based (e.g., should I use C++ or C#? should I use Angular or React?), then just vote to close.

Comment: Related: [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/).